# python : remove multiple entries in one column separated by comma

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this table called sorted_list in excel looking like :

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+
| P33151            | partially reviewed             | 9 | other code                                                                                               | Homo sapiens (Human); Pan troglodytes (Chimpanzee)                              |  784 | 100% |
| B4DMA7            | unreviewed                     | 1 | B4DMA7                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            |  779 | 100% |
| A8K0L9            | unreviewed                     | 1 | A8K0L9                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            |  828 | 100% |
| B4DTP0            | unreviewed                     | 1 | B4DTP0                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            |  525 | 100% |
| D3DSM0            | unreviewed                     | 1 | D3DSM0                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            |  712 | 100% |
| A8K0L1            | unreviewed                     | 1 | A8K0L1                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            |  781 | 100% |
| P06756,L7RXH0     | partially reviewed and UniParc | 8 | P06756; L7RXH0; UPI0001BE65FF; UPI000DF0CE97; UPI0003E68261; UPI0002A11580; UPI0000112063; UPI0012318420 | Homo sapiens (Human); ?                                                         | 1048 | 100% |
| Q59EQ1            | unreviewed                     | 8 | A0A2J8RMA6; Q59EQ1; H3BR78; H3BPQ2; H3BSM4; H3BQH2; H3BP26; H3BQB5                                       | Pongo abelii (Sumatran orangutan) (Pongo pygmaeus abelii); Homo sapiens (Human) |  670 | 100% |
| A0A024R8K7        | partially reviewed and UniParc | 3 | A0A024R8K7; P16144-2; UPI0003EAE94B                                                                      | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            | 1752 | 100% |
| P11279,A0A024RDY3 | partially reviewed             | 3 | P11279; A0A024RDY3; B3KRY3                                                                               | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            |  417 | 100% |
| B4DFP0            | unreviewed                     | 1 | B4DFP0                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            |  382 | 100% |
| J3KRI5            | unreviewed                     | 2 | J3KRI5; H2QB90                                                                                           | Homo sapiens (Human); Pan troglodytes (Chimpanzee)                              |  744 | 100% |
| B2RCN5            | unreviewed                     | 1 | B2RCN5                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            |  916 | 100% |
| Q9NR97            | reviewed                       | 1 | Q9NR97                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            | 1041 | 100% |
| Q02846            | reviewed                       | 1 | Q02846                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            | 1103 | 100% |
| Q9NY15            | reviewed                       | 1 | Q9NY15                                                                                                   | Homo sapiens (Human)                                                            | 2570 | 100% |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+
```

I am interested in matching the values of first column to other table, but the some rows in col1 have multiple values.
I wish to extract each row with single value(remove the part after ',') and then match it with other table's`preppi` column called `preppi['prot1']`

code I used so far is

```
col_one_list = sorted_list['id'].tolist()
print(list(col_one_list))
filepath= "/Users/saheeba/Downloads/preppi_final.csv"
preppi = pd.read_csv(filepath)
df = preppi.loc[preppi['prot1'].isin(col_one_list)]
print(df.shape)
```

But it leave the data in rows with two values in first column e.g; `P06756,L7RXH0` 
Any suggestion, on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new column by splitting the first column on the delimiter (Here a comma) and keeping the first element. For the rows that do not have the delimiter, you get the only element remaining (which the element itself) and for the rest, you should get first element. Once you create that column, apply the logic you already have using that column.

Comment: It didn't worked for me, because for me the number of item in each col is not the same